# node cron job is working

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I am trying to run the code of the node cron job but it is not working when I specify the specific time. Below is the code.

```
var job = new cronJob({
  cronTime: '00 01 16 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
    console.log("hello");
  },
  start: true,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});
job.start();
```

Comment: this code should print `hello` every workday at 01:16:00 AM ?
is that the correct behaviour that you want?

Comment: @NourSammour it should print hello every workday at 04:16:00 pm. I want this behavior.

Comment: `cronTime: '00 16 16 * * 1-5'` should solve your issue

Comment: @NourSammour its not working

Comment: I have also checked by removing job.start(), because start is already set with true, but still not working

Comment: try to drop the `timeZone`

Comment: @NourSammour Thanks it worked :)

Comment: If you can mark/vote up my answer will be great

Comment: @NourSammour done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it should print hello every workday at 04:16:00 pm. I want this behavior

Try to change your code to:

```
var job = new cronJob({
  cronTime: '00 16 16 * * 1-5',
  onTick: function() {
    console.log("hello");
  },
  start: true
});
```